# Selectively strip tags using imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, exif

Is there a way to to selectively strip (metadata) tags using imagemagick? For instance, to remove all GPS information from EXIF metatdata, but keep all the other relevant and good information, such as camera model, date etc.?

Comment: Have you tried searching before posting this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35827136/2836621

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stop Image Magick stripImage() from removing resolution data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35826775/how-do-i-stop-image-magick-stripimage-from-removing-resolution-data)